# Llamar a una ruta por post en Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, rutas, get

Quiero construir un enlace en una vista similar al siguiente:

```
<a href="{{ route('ruta', [parametro=>valor]) }}">Pulsar aquí</a>
```

Sin embargo, al definir la ruta, quiero usar el método POST, así:

```
Route::post('pagina', 'Controlador@metodo')->name('ruta');
```

en lugar de usar GET, así:

```
Route::get('pagina', 'Controlador@metodo')->name('ruta');
```

El objetivo es que el parámetro viaje por post, y no aparezca en la barra de direcciones, pero no quiero usar un formulario, si no un enlace como he puesto en la primera línea. ¿Cómo puede hacerse? Si defino la ruta directamente por post, como en el ejemplo que he puesto, me lanza una excepción.

Comment: Por qué no quieres usar un form?

Comment: cuidado con los conceptos. GET se utiliza para obtener informacion. POST es para crear (subir informacion), PUT para actualizar, DELETE para borrar... Se ha enseñado mucho y mal que se puede "crear" con parametros en la url y que esa era la diferencia con post, pero NO ES ASI. Lo correcto seria un form, o sino un boton con un javascript que envie los parametros que quieres.

Comment: Que recurso planeas que se muestre al pulsar ese enlace?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias técnicas para «camuflar» una petición POST en un botón, tal vez uno de los métodos más comunes (y sencillos), es enviar un formulario «no visible» con dicho enlace, usando el evento onclick:

```
<a class="button" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('my_form').submit();">
 Enviar
</a>
<form action="{{ route('ruta', [parametro=>valor]) }}" method="post" id="my_form">
  @csrf
</form>
```